# Как проверить есть ли id пользователя в базе данных sqlite используя телеграм бота в python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, sqlite3, telegram

Я написал телеграм бота, в котором при нажатии на кнопку "My account" id пользователя должен сверяться с базой данных и если пользователь есть в базе данных то бот напишет "bd check" если пользователя нет то напишет "bd netu"

Но проблема в том что, когда я пытаюсь проверить через `data1 = cur.fetchall()` и пишу `if message.chat.id in data1` то условие выполняется некорректно, оно не сравнивает нормально, возможно из за того что в data1 id сохраняется как (id,), а message.chat.id = id .

Я пробовал даже добавлять эти лишние "(" ")" "," но условие все равно не работает правильно.
Работает только условие elif "bd netu".

Вот мой код

```
def phone(message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2, resize_keyboard=True)
    button_phone = types.KeyboardButton(text="Send contact", request_contact=True)
    akkount = types.KeyboardButton(text="My account")
    keyboard.add(button_phone)
    keyboard.add(akkount)
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Спасибо", reply_markup=keyboard)
    # bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hello World!", reply_markup=bazar)
    # a = "("
    # f = ",)"
    # b = str(chat_id)
    # c = a + b + f
    # print(c)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handler(message):
    if message.text == "My account":
        with sq.connect("bot5.db") as con:
            cur = con.cursor()


            data1=cur.execute("SELECT id FROM info1")
            con.commit()
            rop = []
            data1 = cur.fetchall()
            rop.append(data1)
            chat_id = message.chat.id
            a = "("
            f = ",)"
            b = str(chat_id)
            c = a + b + f
            print(c)
            print(data1)
            # print(*data1)
            # print(rop)
            print(message.chat.id)
            if c in data1:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Bd check")
            elif c not in data1:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Bd netu")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### Пример решения:

```
cur = con.cursor()

chat_id = message.chat.id
exists = cur.execute("SELECT 1 FROM info1 WHERE id = ?", [chat_id]).fetchone()

text = "Bd check" if exists else "Bd netu"
bot.send_message(chat_id, text)
```

Если любопытно как и почему, то посмотрите ниже :)

##### Описание решения:

- Используем поиск через базу данных, передавая `chat_id` в запрос, если что-то есть, то вернется `1`
- Используем метод `fetchone`, т.к. интересует только первое значение. Если с таким `id` в таблице `info1` что-то будет, то вернется кортеж `(1,)`, иначе `None` (это важно для проверки наличия записей в коде, т.к. кортеж на один элемент при проверках будет считаться `True`, а `None` как `False`)
- Не формируем вручную строку запроса с значениями, используем binding-параметры, они помечаются как `?` (для расширения темы гуглим про sql-инъекции). В примере для передачи параметров использовал список, но можно и кортеж `cur.execute("SELECT 1 FROM info1 WHERE id = ?", (chat_id,))`, но, по-мне, он не такой выразительный, как список, особенно, когда параметр один

##### Заметил следующие проблемы в коде:

- `SELECT` без самого условия, что приводит к проверке в коде. А если у вас будет миллион пользователей? :)
- Коммит на `SELECT`. Это не нужно, т.к. ничего в базе не менялось
- Неумелая работа с данными python. Метод `fetchall` вернул список из кортежей, в кортежах находится то, что в `SELECT` указывали, поэтому построение из этого строки ошибка. Решением такого может быть пробег по списку кортежей и поиск нужного, типа: `exists = any(x[0] == chat_id for x in data1)`. Далее, проверить что `if exists: ... else: ...`, можно и в одну строку: `bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Bd check" if exists else "Bd netu")`
- Условие имеет двойную проверку, достаточно `if ...: else`, ведь если `if c in data1:` будет `False`, то `elif c not in data1:` точно будет `True`

Comment: Спасибо большое за детальное объяснение и пример кода!

Comment: @Mirmir, пожалуйста :)